# Replace androidx.lifecycle.Observer by "it"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

Android Studio 3.6

In my fragment:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer

bluetoothPageViewModel.isInitModeLiveData().observe(this,
            Observer<Boolean> { isInitMode ->
             if (isInitMode) {
         // do some code
           })
```

and here my ViewModel:

```
class BluetoothPageViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

private val isInitModeLiveData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()


 fun isInitModeLiveData(): LiveData<Boolean> {
        return isInitModeLiveData
}
```

Nice it's work fine. Nice.

But I can can replace code in fragment like this:

b

```
luetoothPageViewModel.isInitModeLiveData().observe(this, Observer {
            if (it) {
          // do some code
            }
            })
```

And it also work.
Why?

Answer (score 4):

By design, if lambda has one parameter, you can refer to it as `it`. You can also decide to name it - that's what `isInitMode ->` part of code does. Both are correct, both do exactly the same.

Also, naming your parameters might sometimes(not always) add a lot to readability of the code.

Check out this part of documentation:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter